# MYSQL+ Spring Boot two table with same id (default auto increment) column not update properly

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have two tables `customer` and `product`. Both contain one common column `id` as primary key and auto increment.

The issue is while adding new entry it takes the highest value of `id` column from either `customer` or from `product` which has the highest value for `id` column and then auto increment and add for new entry.

In details: in `customer id` has highest value is 7 and in `product` it is 5.

While adding an entry to `product`, it take 8 as `id` value and add new entry.

Answer (score 2):

Instated of using
"@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )" annotation use following

@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")

@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")